# Moodle SQL Configurable reports

Tags: sql, moodle

Is there a way where I can fetch a data from a certain profile field only.

```
SELECT u.username AS 'User Name',
CONCAT(u.firstname,' ',u.lastname) AS 'Full Name',
u.department AS 'Organisation',
c.fullname AS 'Course Name',
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timeenrolled),'%m/%d/%Y') AS 'Enrollment Date',
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted),'%m/%d/%Y') AS 'Completion Date',
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted),INTERVAL 1 YEAR), '%Y-%m-%d') AS 'Expiration Date' 

FROM prefix_course_completions AS p
JOIN prefix_course AS c ON p.course = c.id
JOIN prefix_user AS u ON p.userid = u.id

WHERE 1 = 1
%%FILTER_SUBCATEGORIES:cc.path%% 
%%FILTER_COURSES:Course%%
%%FILTER_USERS:Department%%
%%FILTER_SEARCHTEXT:u.firstname:~%%
ORDER BY u.firstname
```

Can I do something like

**`%%FILTER_USERS:Department="SCIENCE DEPARTMENT"%%`**

so the report will only show users from SCIENCE Department. Thanks in advance

Comment: Anyone? Please? I still haven't found the answer even if I search.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply apply it in the WHERE Clause like:

```
WHERE u.department = 'SCIENCE DEPARTMENT'
```